# Display X-Axis value in Descending order?

Tags: silverlight, charts

In Silverlight toolkit chart control, the X-Axis value is displayed by default in ascending order. How do I make display in descending order?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted it on silverlight forums. This is how we do it:

```
<charts:CategoryAxis Title="x-Label" Orientation="X" SortOrder="Descending"/>
```

Thanks...